# AoG JSON mysterious response parse error for 'order' object in TransactionDecision

Tags: node.js, transactions, actions-on-google, fulfillment

I am trying to develop my first AoG action that works with `transactions` and `order`. In doing so, in the `node.js` fulfillment code I used the exact code as shown in *Build reservations* in https://developers.google.com/actions/transactions/physical/dev-guide-physical-reservations#troubleshooting.

In my fulfillment I use the `order` object as shown on the `Node.js` tab under *2. Build the order* (https://developers.google.com/actions/transactions/physical/dev-guide-physical-reservations#fulfillment_2) 

and the code for the `TransactionDecision` instance under *3. Propose the order* (https://developers.google.com/actions/transactions/physical/dev-guide-physical-reservations#fulfillment_3)

I then use the following code for generating the response:

```
          const order = ... // from 'Build the order'

          let td = new TransactionDecision({
            orderOptions: {
              requestDeliveryAddress: 'false',
            },
            presentationOptions: {
              actionDisplayName: 'RESERVE',
            },
            order: order 
          });

          conv.ask(td);
```

When I try to test this in the Actions on Google Actions Console, I get the following error message in the log:

```
{
 insertId: "63wrc8fa8xoge"  
 labels: {…}  
 logName: "projects/...."  
 receiveTimestamp: "2019-09-24T12:39:19.247945401Z"  
 resource: {…}  
 severity: "ERROR"  
 textPayload: "UnparseableJsonResponse: API Version 2: Failed to parse JSON response string with 'INVALID_ARGUMENT' error: "order: Cannot find field." HTTP Status Code: 200"  
 timestamp: "2019-09-24T12:39:19.240171706Z"  
 trace: "projects/84695521529/traces/ABwppHH_pPd9tThUe9Deu_8jeEcTN_-YcXX-57ciimLmrafv11ERv4dNRNb1Ka2W5r-LM2EjKNZny0tX_1FbgzE"  
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I am using actionssdk:

```
const app = actionssdk();
app.ordersv3 = true;
```

Kind regards,

John Pool

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be simple: I was using a too old version of the *Actions on Google* client library. Upgrading to version 2.11.0 solved the problem.